# Representación de comparación de secuencias

Tags: python

¿Cómo puedo realizar un dotplot en python, que no visualice cuadrados sino líneas? Que permita comparar de forma adecuada las dos secuencias fasta.
He conseguido obtener un dotplot con el siguiente código, pero es para mí imposible interpretar algo.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def dotplot (ruta1,ruta2):
    fichero = open (ruta1,'r')
    secuencia = ''
    for linea in fichero:
        if '>' not in linea:
            lineasinreto = linea.strip()
            secuencia += lineasinreto
    fichero2 = open(ruta2,'r')
    secuencia2 = ''
    for linea in fichero2:
        if '>' not in linea:
            lineasinreto = linea.strip()
            secuencia2+=lineasinreto
    matriz = np.zeros ((len(secuencia),len(secuencia2)))
    for i in range(len(secuencia)):
        for x in range (len(secuencia2)):
            if secuencia[i] ==secuencia2[x]:
                matriz[i,x]=1       
    return matriz

a,=dotplot(os.getcwd()+'/fichero.fa',os.getcwd()+'/fichero1.fa')
plt.matshow(a)
```

Me gustaría obtener algo así:
http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/images/dot_plot_scatter.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A falta de tus datos, examinando la función que los lee deduzco que el resultado es una matriz dispersa con ceros en la mayoría de sus posiciones, y unos aquí y allá en lugares que dependen de los contenidos de los ficheros que has leido.

Crearé una matriz similar, aleatoriamente, con 100 columnas y 50 filas, que contenga 100 unos dispersos al azar:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matriz = np.zeros((100, 50))
for i in range(100):
  matriz[random.randint(0,99), random.randint(0,49)] = 1
```

Matplotlib proporciona la función `scatterplot()` que produce el resultado que buscas, sólo que las entradas que hay que pasarle son dos listas, una con las coordenadas `x` y otra con las coordenadas `y` de los puntos a mostrar. Por suerte es sencillo extraer esta información de nuestra matriz:

```
x, y = np.argwhere(matriz==1).T
```

Ahora ya podemos pintar el *scatterplot*:

```
plt.scatter(x,y, s=50, marker="o")
```

Puedes jugar con los parámetros `s` (tamaño de cada punto) y `marker` (forma de cada punto, prueba con `"*"`, `"D"`, `"."` por ejemplo o [mira todas las opciones](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle.html#matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle). En mi caso sale:

[image: Resultado]